# xPages nested repeat control doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, xpages

Here is my xPage with two repeat controls (the second one is nested)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.MY_SCOPE = new Array();
viewScope.MY_SCOPE.push(["A1", "B1", ["aaa1", "bbb1", "ccc1"]]);
viewScope.MY_SCOPE.push(["A2", "B2", ["aaa2", "bbb2", "ccc2"]]);
viewScope.MY_SCOPE.push(["A3", "B3", ["aaa3", "bbb3", "ccc3"]]);}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30"
        value="#{javascript:viewScope.MY_SCOPE}" var="rowData" indexVar="rowDataIndex"
        repeatControls="true">
        <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData[0]}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
        <xp:repeat id="repeat2" rows="30" var="rowDataSub" indexVar="rowDataSubIndex"
            repeatControls="true">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData[2]}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField2">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowDataSub[0]}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
            <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField3">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowDataSub[1]}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
            <xp:br></xp:br>
        </xp:repeat>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

As a data I'm using array scopeVariable. It works perfect for parent repeat and shows scopeVariable data in computed field computedField1. For nested repeat I use an array that is third element of scopeVariable. But nested repeat doesn't show anything in computed field computedField2. Is anything wrong with my repeats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line of code

```
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowDataSub}]]></xp:this.value>
```

The nested repeat control runs already over all entries in sub array.
So, access current entry with `rowDataSub` instead of `rowDataSub[0]`.

Comment: well, this like works but it shows all components of array in one field computedField2. I need to show regDataSub[0] in computedField2, regDataSub[1] in computedField3, and so on.. I've updated my initial example

Comment: It shows every entry in a separate row. That's why you use the nested repeat control. If you want to have separate fields then don't use repeat control...

Comment: OK.. in nested repeat I want to show 1st element aaa1 as a label, 2nd bbb1 as e.g. a link, 3rd ccc1 e.g as editBox.. Then repeat, aaa2, bbb2, ccc2...

Comment: Then don't use nested repeat. Instead: label is `rowData[2][0]`, link is `rowData[2][1]` and editbox is `rowData[2][2]` within first repeat.